Finding the total numbers between values in TI nspire spreadsheets
I am using TI-nspire spreadsheets
I want to find the number of values that are greater than 5 and less than 10
the numbers are stored in a column called "data" and also in cells A1 to A5
the numbers are {7,4,25,39,9} we can recall it in any formula using the word data or A1:A5 or even {7,4,25,39,9}
I know the answer is 2 but this is a simplified example so I can find the correct formula to solve harder ones
(https://i.sstatic.net/7DUXlceK.png)
I tried all of these commands that keep showing either 0 or syntax errors even if I add or remove quotation marks or add this symbol "≥" is it that I am using this function wrong or is there another function that does what I need? (https://i.sstatic.net/e8f3J2Nv.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/26pQpQZM.png)
countIf(A1:A5, ">5") - countIf(A1:A5, ">=10") outputs: 0
countIf(A1:A5, >5) - countIf(A1:A5, >=10) outputs: syntax error
countIf({7,4,25,39,9}, ">5") - countIf({7,4,25,39,9}, ">=10") outputs: 0
countIf({7,4,25,39,9}, >5) - countIf({7,4,25,39,9}, >=10) outputs: syntax error
countIf(data, ">5") - countIf(data, ">=10") outputs: 0
countIf(data, >5) - countIf(data, >=10) outputs: syntax error
count(A1:A5, ">5") - count(A1:A5, ">=10") outputs: 0
count(A1:A5, >5) - count(A1:A5, >=10) outputs: syntax error
count({7,4,25,39,9}, ">5") - count({7,4,25,39,9}, ">=10") outputs: 0
count({7,4,25,39,9}, >5) - count({7,4,25,39,9}, >=10) outputs: syntax error
count(data, ">5") - count(data, ">=10") outputs: 0
count(data, >5) - count(data, >=10) outputs: syntax error
countif(a1:a5,">5")-countif(a1:a5,"≥10")outputs: 0
countif(a1:a5,>5)-countif(a1:a5,≥10)outputs: syntax error

As as I remember, the syntax for countIf requires you to put a question mark where the value is to be inserted.
Write countIf(a, ?>5) when working with the values in column A.
UPDATE


Like countif(a,"?>5")-countif(a,"?>=10")
or countif(a1:a5,"?>5")-countif(a1:a5,"?>=10")
both output 0

@ArtyArtanis The ?>5 is not meant to be quoted.

Thank you very much!, this one works very well,
to find a value between two numbers I used =countif(a1:a5,?>5)-countif(a1:a5,?≥10)

@ArtyArtanis No problem. Remember to mark the answer as accepted.

I have made some progress and used when function to get the correct answer and made this, it does what is needed, and gives the correct answer, but if the sample size was much bigger like 60 or 100, it would be time consuming writing the same command 100 times, correct me if there is a better or faster way
=when(a1>5 and a1<10,1,0)+when(a2>5 and a2<10,1,0)+when(a3>5 and a3<10,1,0)+when(a4>5 and a4<10,1,0)+when(a5>5 and a5<10,1,0)

